# 404 not found page for SMD colorswatch in catalog dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9

I have successfully installed SMD colorswatch extension on magento. Settings of secure and unsecure Url are correct

other pages are working fine, also colorswatch on frontend working fine.

I updated magento version to 1.9.2, after updation of magento version I am receiving 404 not found page error in admin.

Please let me know about what I am missing for this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your config.xml file and comment below code and write new code that I am suggesting

```
<!-- START DEFINED BACKEND ROUTE -->
<!--admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <colorswatch>SMDesign_Colorswatch</colorswatch>
                    <frontName>colorswatch</frontName>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin-->
<!-- END DEFINED BACKEND ROUTE -->  

<admin>
<routers>
  <colorswatch>
    <use>admin</use>
    <args>
      <module>SMDesign_Colorswatch</module>
      <frontName>colorswatch</frontName>
    </args>
  </colorswatch>
</routers>
</admin>
```

and open adminhtml.xml and write below code or create adminhtml.xml if it is not there in etc folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <catalog translate="title" module="catalog">
        <children>
            <colorswatch translate="title" module="catalog">
                <title>SMD ColorSwatch</title>
                <action>colorswatch/adminhtml_colorswatch/attributes</action>
                <sort_order>25</sort_order>                 
            </colorswatch>
        </children>
    </catalog>
</menu>




<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <smdesign_colorswatch translate="title" module="colorswatch">
                                <title>Config SMDesign Magento ColorSwatch</title>
                                <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                                </smdesign_colorswatch>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>


                <catalog translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <children>
                        <colorswatch translate="title">
                        <title>SMDesign Color Swatch</title>
                            <children>
                                <swatch_attributes translate="title">
                                    <title>Manage Attributes</title>
                                </swatch_attributes>
                                <swatch_images translate="title">
                                    <title>Manage Attribute Images</title>
                                </swatch_images>
                            </children>
                        </colorswatch>
                    </children>
                </catalog>

            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
  </config>
```

Comment: thanks murtuza for your help. After placing above code I am not able to see SMD colorswatch under Catalog menu.

Comment: app/code/community/SMDesign/Colorswatch/etc/config.xml-----------------
app/code/community/SMDesign/Colorswatch/etc/adminhtml.xml

Comment: I am login with admin.

Comment: Try to login with root admin Then only you can see the menu And assign permission to diffrent role in admin

Comment: Sorry, I am login with root admin, but I can not see link

Comment: You are looking in catalog->SmdColorswatch or other place ?

Comment: I have just make changes in config.xml and now it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.9.2 comes with patch bundle SUPEE-6788. This patch fixes several security issues. Check this Official [Magento technical-details about SUPEE-6788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details).

From your issue, this seems due to admin route changes. So make changes according to this report.